# extract several columns in one op from tf.tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In recent TensorFlow (`1.13` or `2.0`) is there a way to extract non-contiguous slices from a tensor in one pass? How to do it?
For instance with the following tensor:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

I want to extract columns 1 and 3 in one op to get:

```
2 4
6 8
```

However it seems I cannot do it in a single op with slicing.
What's the correct/fastest/most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Using `tf.gather(tensor, columns, axis=1)` (`TF1.x`, `TF2`):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=tf.float32)
columns = [1, 3]

print(tf.gather(tensor, columns, axis=1).numpy())
%timeit -n 10000 tf.gather(tensor, columns, axis=1)
# [[2. 4.]
#  [6. 8.]]
```

```
82.6 µs ± 5.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**2.** With indexing (`TF1.x`, `TF2`):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=tf.float32)
columns = [1, 3] # <--columns you want to extract

transposed = tf.transpose(tensor)
sliced = [transposed[c] for c in columns]
stacked = tf.transpose(tf.stack(sliced, axis=0))
# print(stacked.numpy()) # <-- TF2, TF1.x-eager

with tf.Session() as sess:  # <-- TF1.x
    print(sess.run(stacked))
# [[2. 4.]
#  [6. 8.]]
```

Wrapping it to a function and running `%timeit` in `tf.__version__=='2.0.0-alpha0'`:

```
154 µs ± 2.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Decorating it with `@tf.function` is more than 2 times faster:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=tf.float32)
columns = [1, 3] # <--columns you want to extract
@tf.function
def extract_columns(tensor=tensor, columns=columns):
    transposed = tf.transpose(tensor)
    sliced = [transposed[c] for c in columns]
    stacked = tf.transpose(tf.stack(sliced, axis=0))
    return stacked

%timeit -n 10000 extract_columns()
```

```
66.8 µs ± 2.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**3.** One-liner for *eager execution* (`TF2`, `TF1.x-eager`):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=tf.float32)
columns = [1, 3] # <--columns you want to extract

res = tf.transpose(tf.stack([t for i, t in enumerate(tf.transpose(tensor))
                             if i in columns], 0))
print(res.numpy())
# [[2. 4.]
#  [6. 8.]]
```

`%timeit` in `tf.__version__=='2.0.0-alpha0'`:

```
242 µs ± 2.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**4.** Use `tf.one_hot()` to specify rows/columns and then `tf.boolean_mask()` to extract these rows/columns (`TF1.x`, `TF2`):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=tf.float32)
columns = [1, 3] # <--columns you want to extract

mask = tf.one_hot(columns, tensor.get_shape().as_list()[-1])
mask = tf.reduce_sum(mask, axis=0)
res = tf.transpose(tf.boolean_mask(tf.transpose(tensor), mask))
# print(res.numpy()) # <-- TF2, TF1.x-eager

with tf.Session() as sess: # TF1.x
    print(sess.run(res))
# [[2. 4.]
#  [6. 8.]]
```

`%timeit` in `tf.__version__=='2.0.0-alpha0'`:

```
494 µs ± 4.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: thanks a lot !
do you have any idea about which one is going to be faster?

Comment: Added `%timeit` log. The first one is fastest.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all odd numbered columns with a combination of reshapes and a slice:

```
N = 4
M = 10
input = tf.constant(np.random.rand(M, N))
slice_odd = tf.reshape(tf.reshape(input, (-1, 2))[:,1], (-1, int(N/2)))
```

Comment: thanks! however I'm not looking specifically to get all odd-numbered columns
My question was more general